# Best framework for build in help system for java based web application

Tags: java, frameworks, documentation, documentation-generation

I am looking for a framework that will help me to build help system for my java based web application. Would be great if it will be the system that easy to use and maintain but provides all features average help system needs.

At the moment I see it as a some kind of system that will produce bunch of html pages with search functionality located in http://host/MySuperApp/docs/. The documentation will have a lot of code snippets and graphics. At the moment multilanguage support is not really needed even it is standard feature this days.

Any other features that are great but I wasn't thinking about them yet are welcome.

Any suggestions are appretiated,
Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: What does the application do?

Comment: The application is a framework that help to build for enterprise companies BI solutions. The help system will be designed for developers and administrators of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, I worked with the [Eclipse Help System](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp). Eclipse is not necessarily needed to integrate it in your project. Its helpfiles are also based on .html pages. Unfortunatly I dont know if they continue developing it, but at this time it already provided all the aspects you would expect from a help system.

There are a lot examples out there on how to integrate it in your project, but its possible, that maybe there are already better frameworks today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/. It was initially created for python. Very easy to use.